# WCF Exception: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, service

When I call a WCF service I get an exception:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

When I use Wireshark packet analyzer filter on http the larges packet sent is 1226 bytes, which is way bellow the limit of 65536 bytes. Any suggestions to why this exception is thrown?

[image: Screendump from wireshark]

Protocol-Length-Info

Server stack trace:

```
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
... 
    <binding 
        name="WSHttpBinding_IService" 
        closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
        transactionFlow="false" 
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        allowCookies="false">
        <readerQuotas 
          maxDepth="32" 
          maxStringContentLength="8192" 
          maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
          maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <reliableSession 
          ordered="true" 
          inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
          enabled="false" />
        <security 
          mode="Message">
          <transport 
            clientCredentialType="Windows" 
            proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message 
          clientCredentialType="Certificate" 
          negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Code that I suspect causes the exception:

```cs
public LoanPlan CalculateLoanPlans(string productName)
{
    var loanPlan = new LoanPlan
    {
        Details = new[]
        {
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 5000, Periods = 6},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 5000, Periods = 12},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 5000, Periods = 24},

            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 10000, Periods = 6},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 10000, Periods = 12},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 10000, Periods = 24},

            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 15000, Periods = 6},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 15000, Periods = 12},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 15000, Periods = 24},

            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 20000, Periods = 6},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 20000, Periods = 12},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 20000, Periods = 24},

            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 30000, Periods = 6},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 30000, Periods = 12},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 30000, Periods = 24},

            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 40000, Periods = 6},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 40000, Periods = 12},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 40000, Periods = 24},

            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 50000, Periods = 6},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 50000, Periods = 12},
            new PlanDetails {LoanAmount = 50000, Periods = 24}
        },
        TaxProcent = _taxPercent,
     };
     Parallel.ForEach(loanPlan.Details, detail =>
     {
         var result = Calculate(productName, Convert.ToInt32(detail.LoanAmount), detail.Periods, null);

         detail.ActualPaymentCost = result.ActualPaymentCost;
         detail.CreditCost = result.CreditAmount;
         detail.MonthlyPayment = result.MonthlyPayment;
         detail.MonthlyPaymentCost = result.MonthlyPaymentCredit;
     });

     var firstDetail = loanPlan.Details[0];
     var firstResult = Calculate(productName, Convert.ToInt32(firstDetail.LoanAmount), firstDetail.Periods, null);

     loanPlan.MonthlyFee = firstResult.MonthlyFee;
     loanPlan.MonthlyInterest = firstResult.MonthlyInterest;

     return loanPlan;
}
```

The Calculate method contains the servicecall.

Comment: Can you post your config entries?

Comment: Also please set the following readerQuotas within your binding element in your config on both client and server: <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="64" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" /> and the datacontract serializer in your behaviorconfiguration element : <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" /> and set the maxRecievedMessageSize as shown: <binding name="mybinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

Comment: Doesn't the error come from the server reply rather than your request?

Comment: You need to have the same settings on both client and server

Comment: Why is the instinctive reaction of most, when faced with such problems of lengths in WCF, to suggest limiting all length-related properties to no less than their maximum capacity?

Comment: Added config to post. I have changed it to match what i could find in the service info file(configuration91.svcinfo) but no luck.  I had values similar to Rajesh's first comment, but i got the exception. I do think the exception happens on the serverside but, i want to be sure before i get them to change it.  The strange thing is that i don't think there is any package sent that exceeds the limit.

Comment: Since you verified via wireshark that the data being sent is not exceeding 64k, I would not just arbitrarily set all your values to int.MaxValue - even if it does make the problem go away. It would be very reassuring to understand **why** increasing these values work, seeing as how the data being sent is so small (all of this is under the assumption that you are looking at the correct wireshark data)

Answer (score 1):

Increase maxStringContentLength & maxArrayLength="2147483647" on both server and client. Check the below link which explains in detail

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f570823a-8581-45ba-8b0b-ab0c7d7fcae1

Comment: I think the question is not how to fix it, but why it happens

Comment: And this is a very temperamental fix, at best.

Comment: I have done that on the client. I want to be sure that this is the problem before i make the serverside people change the config. The strange thing is that i cannot see any packages larger than the limit being sent when i use wireshark.

Comment: Yes you need to increase on both Server & Client.

Comment: The thing is that i suspect that it's the message size that is the real problem. Because it works for a short while, but when i run a specific method that makes a specific call to the service I get the exception. An the Methods that did work before now also throws the same exception. I added a code snippet to my post that explains what call i suspect is causing it.

Comment: It neednot be the request. It can also be that response is so big and hence this exception can happen.